# Invalid expression type for '#pragma omp atomic' with OpenACC

Tags: c++, multithreading, openacc

I've been toying with OpenACC as an alternative to writing low-level CUDA code. I have a OpenMP implementation that looks something like this in C++:

```
int main() {
...
Eigen::ArrayXXf grid = Eigen::ArrayXXf::Zero(num_elements);
...
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(...) shared(grid)
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
... // parallelized part of loop goes here
#pragma omp critical
grid += f(...);
}
```

The grid must be added as a single-thread operation, hence the `#pragma omp critical`. This compiles fine with `gcc-7.2.0`. As a first-pass, naive implementation with OpenACC, I tried

```
int main() {
...
Eigen::ArrayXXf grid = Eigen::ArrayXXf::Zero(num_elements);
...
#pragma acc parallel loop
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
... // parallelized part of loop goes here
#pragma acc atomic
grid += f(...);
}
```

On compiling with `gcc-7.2.0` and `pgc++`, I get an error that says `invalid expression type for '#pragma omp atomic'`, which I thought was strange to throw an OpenMP error when using OpenACC. Using `#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:grid)` also threw an error when compiling, saying `user defined reduction not found for 'grid'`.

Why is it throwing this error, and how can I ensure there are no race conditions with `grid`? Is there a way to manually acquire lock within an OpenACC thread?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you can use `Eigen::ArrayXXf` type in an OpenACC accelerator region.  Furthermore, I think OpenACC would have no idea of what is the proper definition of either an atomic operation on that type, or a reduction operation on that type (that is the explanation for your 2nd error message).  What compile command line are you passing to `pgc++` ?

Comment: I was afraid of that; looks like I'll need to use standard vectors/arrays. The compile command I'm using is `pgc++ -ta=tesla -std=c++11 -I ./path/to/eigen -o main main.cpp`

Comment: The OpenACC standard's committee is discussing adding user defined reductions.  They gotten requests for this support.  The challenge will be if it would be performant given the reduction could be across million of threads. Though for now, only fundamental data types can be used in OpenACC atomics or reductions.